# gender of superlative

Tags: gender, superlativ

There are these four sentences:

> du bist der Schnellste

> das Wichtigste ist die Ernährung

> Das Beste, was er zu bieten hat, ist seine Wohnung.

> Du bist echt die Beste

how do we determine the gender for superlative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gender of gender-flexible items aligns to the gender of the noun they refer to. This is a general rule. But there are corner cases.

> du bist der Schnellste

This refers to someone of **arbitrary** real-world gender. Arbitrary because of generic masculinum. While

> du bist die Schnellste

refers to someone of **female** real-world gender.

> das Wichtigste ist die Ernährung

This refers to **things** to consider, and it's **das Ding**. Hence neuter.

> Das Beste was er zu bieten hat, ist seine Wohnung.

Same here.

> Du bist echt die Beste.

Same as above, it's **someone** because of *du*, and that someone is explictly female.

— Always mark women as female. If you don't know the real-world gender, use generic masculinum. —

Comment: @Janke thanks a lot for your answer. It's very clear.